# push an assoc object into array

Tags: javascript

says I've this :

```
var user = [{'id':1,'gender':'male'},{'id':2,'gender':'female'}]
```

I want to use push() to insert

```
'owner':true
```

into the first array so that it become like this

```
var user = [{'id':1,'gender':'male','owner':true},{'id':2,'gender':'female'}]
```

I tried

```
user[0].push({'owner':true});
```

but it doesn't work tht way.

Comment: And so what's the question? Have you tried to do it?

Comment: user[0].owner = true. is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @attila I want that output by using push()

Comment: @PatrickQ said here 'I want to use push to insert'

Comment: @attila so push is not the correct way? I don't know..

Comment: No what you should make object classes not object literals . . You are using the wrong type of object to achieve desired effect

Comment: `.push()` is a method which appends onto _arrays_ `[]`. You are just looking to set an object `{}` property, which is done exactly as @attila suggests `user[0].owner = true;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not pushing an object into an array, you are pushing an object into an object.
You can do this by using jquery's [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) method.

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

Comment: You shouldnt use jquery if not neccessary

Comment: Depends on what time you want to live in, seems to be your opinion.

Comment: In that case, Attila gave you your answer. Anyhow, I just wanted to indicate that you are not pushing an object into an array, which is what you seemed to be thinking.

Comment: @KimGysen I was not saying it to be rude. What I meant was that people take the convince of using jquery without fully understanding the JS language

Comment: Agreed. By the way, my answer is incorrect, I was tired yesterday. He is indeed just setting an extra property on an object, not pushing an object into an existing object.

Answer (score 1):

@Kim Gysen gave you a solution that works. I think you're getting the logic between Arrays and Objects confused I just wanted to give you a solution using only JavaScript that may help you understand just what's going on here. Using libraries like jQuery are a great way to save time but for you I think it would be helpful to have a more comprehensive understanding.

```
user[0]['owner'] = true;
```

In the code above you are accessing your array by the 0th index which in this case is "'id':1" and adding a new property to it using Bracket Notation. Another way to do this would be using Dot Notation:

```
user[0].owner = true;
```

Think about the process of adding a property to an object:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj['newKey'] = "I'm a new value";
myObj['newKey2'] = "I'm an even newer value!";
```

The reason I gave you an answer is it may seem convenient to use jQuery but understanding JavaScript principles and syntax will help you out in the long run. Some good resources for you I'd suggest are [CodeSchool](http://www.codeschool.com) and [CodeAcademy](http://www.codeacademy.com)